# Pdfbox PDFTextStripperByArea coordinates shifted

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am having issues with coordinates. The PDFTextStripperByArea region seems to be pushed too high.

Consider the following example snippet:

```
...
PDPage page = (PDPage) allPages.get(0);
PDFTextStripperByArea stripper = new PDFTextStripperByArea();

// define region for extraction -- the coordinates and dimensions are x, y, width, height
Rectangle2D.Float region = new Rectangle2D.Float(x, y, width, height);
stripper.addRegion("test region", region);

// overlay the region with a cyan rectangle to check if I got the coordinates and dimensions right 
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, true, true);
contentStream.setNonStrokingColor( Color.CYAN );
contentStream.fillRect(x, y, width, height );
contentStream.close();

// extract the text from the defined region
stripper.extractRegions(page);
String content = stripper.getTextForRegion("test region"); 
... 
document.save(...); ...
```

The cyan rectangle overlays the desired region nicely. On the other hand, stripper misses a couple of lines at the bottom of the rectangle and includes couple of lines above the rectangle -- it looks like it is shifted "upwards" (by y coordinate). What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text is usually contained inside a *positioning rectangle*. Sometimes, the text is not at the expected position inside that rectangle, and PDFBox uses that rectangle to try and guess where the text is located. So if text starts outside the capture area and flows into it, it might not be extracted.

Rough sketch: Textbox starts outside the capture area but text flows inside it. It might not be captured.

```
____________
|Page      |
|   _______|
|   |Area ||
|   |     ||
| ..|.....||
| ⁞ |Text⁞||
| ⁞ |____⁞||
| ⁞......⁞ |
|__________|
```

Comment: Hi, I have almost the same problem: I extract blocks from a PDF document and would like to draw rectangles depending on their coordinates. I get the correct width and height but, as you mentioned, the final rectangles are vertically shifted: the first line of the blocks is not included in the rectangle.
Is there any trick to avoid that?

Comment: @NicolasW. Pdfbox has problems with guessing where text actually is as opposed to where it started - so if your text starts outside the rectangle and flows inside it, it might not be captured. The trick is to try a slightly larger capture area so as to capture the text that starts outside your current capture region. I didn't find anything smarter than that.

Comment: Note that Rectangle2D.Float() expects x and y to be upper-left corner coordinates and the fillRect() method of PDPageContentStream expects lower-left corner coordinates

Comment: And PDPageContentStream expects coordinates with the origin in the lower-left corner of the document.

Answer (score 2):

As Christian said in his comment, the problem is that the coordinate system for the fillRect() method and the one for the PDFTextStripperByArea are different.

The first expects the origin to be the lower-left corner of the page, while the second expects it to be the upper-left.

So, to make it work, change the region given to the PDFTextStripperByArea to:

```
Rectangle2D.Float region = new Rectangle2D.Float(x, ph - y - height, width, height);
```

where ph is the page height:

```
float ph = page.getMediaBox().getUpperRightY();
```

**PS:** I know this is a very old question, but Google brought me here when I faced the same problem, so I will add my answer.

Comment: *"The first expects the origin to be the lower-left corner of the page"* - even more exactly: it expects coordinates as defined by the crop box / media box. The media box *often* has the origin in the lower left corner but *not always*. Thus, a generic solution also translates *x* accordingly.