# Extracting only the croped data using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have a requirement to extract a part of pdf page using the user-specified coordinates. So far, I have used cropbox from PDFBox to create a cropbox at the desired location

```
document_ =  new PDDocument();
document_.addPage(page_);
page_.setCropBox(new PDRectangle(startX,startY,width,pageHeight));
```

This gives the expected pdf clipped from the page when I save the document.
But when I try to get all the text from the document using
**PDFTextStripper** it returns me all the text outside the cropbox also.

I also tried **PDFTextStripperByArea** the list of Text returned is invalid. I am using the below code

```
super.addRegion("test", document.getPage(0).getCropBox().toGeneralPath().getBounds2D());
super.extractRegions(document.getPage(0));
super.getTextForRegion("test");
```

What is the mistake here? how do I properly extract the text only inside the cropbox

Comment: That method uses java coordinates for some reason, not PDF coordinates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pdfbox PDFTextStripperByArea coordinates shifted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727419/pdfbox-pdftextstripperbyarea-coordinates-shifted)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr No it isn't transforming the coordinates properly. Anyways, I found a workaround. Thanks for the response :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by manually checking text and image contents. If they are inside cropbox by comparing the coordinates.

```
if((textItem.getStartXPos() + this.cropbox.getLowerLeftX()) >= this.cropbox.getLowerLeftX() &&
  (textItem.getEndXPos() + this.cropbox.getLowerLeftX()) <= (this.cropbox.getLowerLeftX() + this.cropbox.getWidth()) &&
  this.cropbox.getLowerLeftY() <= (this.cropbox.getLowerLeftY()+textItem.getStartYPos())                             
  &&(this.cropbox.getLowerLeftY()+textItem.getStartYPos())<=this.cropbox.getUpperRightY())
            this.pageData.addTextItem(textItem);
```